# how to use GradientExplainer in SHAP library (Tensorflow 2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, shap

Would you prompt me, what arguments to put in `shap.GradientExplainer()` in SHAP library (using Tensorflow 2.0).

There is the only [example](https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/gradient_explainer/Explain%20an%20Intermediate%20Layer%20of%20VGG16%20on%20ImageNet.html) in internet linked with images classification.
In the example, the function accepts 2 inputs as the 1st argument:

```
model.layers[7].input, model.layers[-1].output
```

The full code snippet:

```
# explain how the input to the 7th layer of the model explains the top two classes
def map2layer(x, layer):
    feed_dict = dict(zip([model.layers[0].input], [preprocess_input(x.copy())]))
    return K.get_session().run(model.layers[layer].input, feed_dict)
e = shap.GradientExplainer((model.layers[7].input, model.layers[-1].output), map2layer(preprocess_input(X.copy()), 7))
shap_values,indexes = e.shap_values(map2layer(to_explain, 7), ranked_outputs=2)
```

But my model is Sequential [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078946/how-to-get-reproducible-results-keras-tensorflow/61113427#61113427).
When I try to put 2 inputs as the first argument

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values((model.input, model.output))
```

, an error occurs

```
Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors.
```

When I use 1 input

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(model.output)
```

, another error occurs:

```
Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 46 but received input with shape `[None, 1]`
```

Then, I try to input data from dataset:

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df3.to_numpy()[:100,:])
```

The error occurs:

```
KeyError: 31467
```

If you don't have an answer, may be, you know another example of using GradientExplainer.

Comment: As an alternative, alibi's [integrated gradients explanation](https://docs.seldon.io/projects/alibi/en/latest/methods/IntegratedGradients.html) does a similar computation and does work with TF2 for me.